# Dialogflow - store data in UK - is it possible?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

We have a client who want us to build bot, we prefer to use Dialogflow for that, however, the client has a requirement that all data should be stored within UK - is there any possibility to satisfy that need while still using Dialogflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to choose where your data is hosted.